# Java: Why aren't NullPointerExceptions called NullReferenceExceptions?

Tags: java

Was this an oversight?  Or is it to do with the JVM?

Comment: Because pointer and reference is the same thing. It does not matter wich synonym you take to represent the idea.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Java does indeed have pointers--pointers on which you cannot perform pointer arithmetic.

From the venerable [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1):

> There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types (§4.2) and reference types (§4.3). There are, correspondingly, two kinds of data values that can be stored in variables, passed as arguments, returned by methods, and operated on: primitive values (§4.2) and reference values (§4.3).

And [later](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An *object* is a *class instance* or an *array*.
>
> The reference values (often just *references*) are *pointers* to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

(emphasis theirs)

So, to interpret, if you write:

```
Object myObj = new Object();
```

then `myObj` is a *reference type* which contains a *reference value* that is itself a *pointer* to the newly-created `Object`.

Thus if you set `myObj` to `null` you are setting the *reference value* (aka *pointer*) to `null`. Hence a NullPointerException is reasonably thrown when the variable is dereferenced.

Don't worry: this topic has been [heartily debated](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_thread/thread/65bf7e9d6bffb1b9/) before.

Comment: A Java reference is not necessarily a pointer to a fixed address in memory, however. Java permits JVM implementations with features such as copying garbage collectors that move objects around in memory. "myObj is a reference type which contains a reference value..." is correct, but "...that is itself a pointer to the newly-created Object" is not. A Java reference is an abstract type with specified semantics. An implementation of Java references *could* use simple pointers, but is not *required* to. NullPointerException could have just as easily been named NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 3):

In Java they use the nomenclature REFERENCE for referring to dynamically created objects. In previous languages, it is named POINTER. Just as the naming of METHODS in object oriented languages has taken over from former FUNCTION's and PROCEDURE's in earlier (object oriented as well as not object oriented) languages. There is no particular better or worse in this naming or new standard, it is just another way of naming the phenomenon of being able to create former dynamic objects, hanging in the air (heap space) and being referred to by a fixed object reference (or dynamic reference also hanging in the air). The authors of the new standard (use of METHODS and REFERENCES) particularly mentioned that the new standards were implemented to make it conformant with the upcoming planning systems - such as UML and UP, where the use of the Object oriented terminology prescribes use of ATTRIBUTES, METHODS and REFERENCES, and not VARIABLES, FUNCTIONS and POINTERS.

Now, you may think now, that it was merely a renaming, but that would be simplifying the description of the process and not be just to the long road which the languages have taken in the name of development. A method is different in nature from a procedure, in that it operates within a scope of a class, while the procedure in its nature operates on the global scope. Similarly an attribute is not just a new name for variable, as the attribute is a property of a class (and its instance - an object). Similarly the reference, which is the question behind this little writing here, is different in that it is typed, thus it does  not have the typical property of pointers, being raw references to memory cells, thus again, a reference is a structured reference to memory based objects.

Now, inside of Java, that is - in the stomach of Java, there is an arbitration layer between the underlying C-code and the Java code (the Virtual Machine). In that arbitration layer, an abstraction occurs in that the underlying (bare metal) implementation of the references, as done by the Virtual machine, protects the references from referring bare metal (memory cells without structure). The raw truth is therefore, that the NullPointerException is truly a Null Pointer Exception, and not just a Null Reference Exception. However, that truth may be completely irrelevant for the programmer in the Java environment, as he/she will not at any point be in contact with the bare metal JVM.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer is that we'll never really know the real answer.

I suspect that some time before Java 1.0 was released, someone defined a class called `NullPointerException`.  Either that person got the name wrong, or the terminology hadn't stabilized; i.e. the decision to use the term "reference" instead of "pointer" hadn't been made.

Either way, it is likely that by the time the inconsistency<sup>1</sup> was noticed it couldn't be fixed without breaking backwards compatibility.

But this is just conjecture.

---

<sup>1 - You can find other minor inconsistencies like this in the standard Java SE libraries if you look really hard.  And a few more serious issues that couldn't be fixed for the same reason.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I guess it has to do with the fact that the JVM is coded in C++. Apart from that, pointers and references are nearly similar. You could say that the reference mechanism in Java is implemented using C++ pointers and the name 'NullPointerException' allows that implementation detail to shine through.