# Why does Java have a "NullPointerException" when there are no pointers in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, nullpointerexception

Why do I get an exception called [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if in Java there is no such concept as a pointer?

Comment: Because it *should* have been called `NullReferenceException`, but someone wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: This. One of my pet Java peeves.

Comment: @tzaman +1 the longer I'm studying Java the more I dislike it for inconsistency and self contradiction.

Comment: Just wait till you get into the _wonderful_ world of Java generics. _<shudder>_

Comment: @tzaman Are they not suppose to be equivalent of C++ templates?

Comment: What they're _supposed to be_ and what they _are_ are two vastly different things. Read about Type Erasure, you'll see.

Comment: probably because the exception was created when java was still trying to almost be be c++... oh wait

Comment: @Justin I'm glad they gave up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Why aren't NullPointerExceptions called NullReferenceExceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101072/java-why-arent-nullpointerexceptions-called-nullreferenceexceptions)

Comment: because pointer and reference is the same thing.

Comment: No, it is not the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this is one of the first annoying things I learned when learning Java LOL.
It really should be called NullReferenceException, NoObjectException or DereferenceException as paxdiablo mentioned.
References don't even have to represented internally as pointers and you shouldn't have to care.
"Most VMs including Sun's use handles, not pointers. A handle is a pointer to a pointer so who knows how they came up with using that?"
Oh Microsoft's Java VM actually does use pointers rather than handles so go figure.

Comment: But a reference is nothing but an immutable pointer, at least conceptually, hence ....

Answer (score 11):

There are no *general purpose* pointers in Java, that you can easily manipulate by adding and subtracting arbitrary values like in C. This can lead to all sorts of problems for those unused to them.

However, Java still needs to distinguish between an object and "no object". It's just the name of the exception that means you're trying to use an object reference that doesn't have a backing object behind it.

You could just as easily call it `NoObjectException` or `DereferenceException`, or one of a myriad of other names to minimise the possibility that people would think Java had general purpose pointers.

But `NullPointerException` is what the language creators opted for, probably because they were used to coding in C and/or C++.

Comment: If only null would have been included in the type system :-/

Comment: @paxidiablo so why on earth they invented final instead of using const. And if you think about it final isn't that descriptive as const is.

Comment: Because const would define a constant. Final is slightly different to the const from C++ inasmuch as you can delay setting the final and, once set, it can't be changed. It seems to me that final is _exactly_ the right term. Once you set it, bang, that's the final value it's allowed to have.

Comment: Java is object-oriented (or so I have been told). So why does it need to distinguish between an object and "no object"? In an object-oriented system, a "null pointer/reference" would be equivalent to a NullObject or an UndefinedObject. This object would, most probably, not understand most of the messages sent to it and trigger an error that way, but there's no need for a "NullPointerException". The real reason is the last sentence of the answer. 'Actually I made up the term "object-oriented", and I can tell you I did not have C++ in mind.' (Alan Kay)

Answer (score 4):

Technically thats correct, it really should be called NullReferenceException

Comment: Reference is the same as pointer. Saying that one synonym must be used but not the other is nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Because internally object variables are pointers to those objects. However, you don't get the pointer value except by calling System.identityHashCode(object) on most JVM implementations, which returns the pointer to the object.

EDIT: You are almost all right, I was almost wrong: identityHashCode is much more complex than returning just a pointer. I just took a look at the JVM source, and they implented a few hashcode generators. However, at least in the case where hashCode (a constant? i don't know) is a constant, they return the object pointer. Here is their source for the curious:

```
static inline intptr_t get_next_hash(Thread * Self, oop obj) {
  intptr_t value = 0 ;
  if (hashCode == 0) {
     // This form uses an unguarded global Park-Miller RNG,
     // so it's possible for two threads to race and generate the same RNG.
     // On MP system we'll have lots of RW access to a global, so the
     // mechanism induces lots of coherency traffic.
     value = os::random() ;
  } else
  if (hashCode == 1) {
     // This variation has the property of being stable (idempotent)
     // between STW operations.  This can be useful in some of the 1-0
     // synchronization schemes.
     intptr_t addrBits = intptr_t(obj) >> 3 ;
     value = addrBits ^ (addrBits >> 5) ^ GVars.stwRandom ;
  } else
  if (hashCode == 2) {
     value = 1 ;            // for sensitivity testing
  } else
  if (hashCode == 3) {
     value = ++GVars.hcSequence ;
  } else
  if (hashCode == 4) {
     value = intptr_t(obj) ;
  } else {
     // Marsaglia's xor-shift scheme with thread-specific state
     // This is probably the best overall implementation -- we'll
     // likely make this the default in future releases.
     unsigned t = Self->_hashStateX ;
     t ^= (t << 11) ;
     Self->_hashStateX = Self->_hashStateY ;
     Self->_hashStateY = Self->_hashStateZ ;
     Self->_hashStateZ = Self->_hashStateW ;
     unsigned v = Self->_hashStateW ;
     v = (v ^ (v >> 19)) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8)) ;
     Self->_hashStateW = v ;
     value = v ;
  }

  value &= markOopDesc::hash_mask;
  if (value == 0) value = 0xBAD ;
  assert (value != markOopDesc::no_hash, "invariant") ;
  TEVENT (hashCode: GENERATE) ;
  return value;
}
```

Comment: @Daniel just out of curiuosity, and in what variable type you store this pointer?

Comment: The pointer itself is an int. So on 64bit systems, the hash might be something slightly different (like the 4 upper bytes xord to the 4 lower bytes of the address).

Comment: @Knowing it returns an int.   But it is _not_ a pointer.  It's a ... (wait for it) ... hashcode.  Which in some JVMs is a function of the address, but it doesn't have to be.  The behavior isn't specified by the JLS.  

And incidentally, because it's a hashcode, two objects can have identical idenityHashCode() values.

I'm not going to downvote, but the last part of Daniel's answer is incorrect: it is wrong on more than one level to say that identityHashCode values are pointers.

Comment: @Daniel, references cannot be pointers internally, because pointer and reference is the same thing. They are synonyms.

Comment: @Val: On some systems, references are pointers which are identified in metadata so that if the GC freezes a program's execution and examines the call stack, it can determine where every live pointer/reference to an unpinned object is located.  While the program is frozen, the GC can copy an object to a new location and replace every pointer to it with a pointer to the new copy; some clever algorithms can make this surprisingly cheap to do.  An "ordinary" pointers can only exist to an object if it's pinned; the GC can't tell where all ordinary pointers are, but it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Because all the variables(on RHS of assignment) you declare are references to some objects in heap space. If a reference is not pointing any where then on accessing of that variable throws nullpointerexception.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an object with let's say a list as an attribute and you don't explicitly allocate space for it, the running program will throw you that error.

Look into a debugger (Eclipse or what not) to see what your objects holds when you don't initialize them properly and then things are going to be pretty clear.

I think it was done so that there is a notion between object that have space in the memory and those that don't.