# Null pointer exception when getting the value from query in java

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I am fetching the value using query

```
SELECT t.revision_no 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX( CONVERT( revision_no, signed INT ) ) AS revision_no 
    FROM atps_dc 
    WHERE DATE =  '"+date+"' 
    GROUP BY CONVERT( revision_no, signed INT )) 
INNER JOIN atps_dc t 
ON t.revision_no = r.revision_no AND t.date =  '"+date+"'";
```

and trying to set this value using this

```
bA.setRev_no(rs2.getString("revision_no"));
```

but the compiler is giving the null pointer exception.
Please help me, how can I resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

compiler doesn't give `NullPointerException` it is `RuntimeException`, You are pointing `bA` to `null` and then trying to invoke method on it and so the `NullPointerException`

```
DC_ChangeA bA=null; 
bA.setRev_no(rs2.getString("revision_no"));
```

try `DC_ChangeA bA = new DC_ChangeA()` or proper initialization in the place of `DC_ChangeA bA = null`

---

**See**

- [Why does Java have a "NullPointerException" when there are no pointers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787338/nullpointerexception)