# Why does Java have NullPointerException instead of NullReferenceException?

Tags: java, naming

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)
>   [Java: Why aren't NullPointerExceptions called NullReferenceExceptions ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101072/java-why-arent-nullpointerexceptions-called-nullreferenceexceptions)

Our of idle curiosity, does anyone know why the null reference exception in Java was called NullPointerException?

It seems counterintuitive that in a new language that officially has no pointers a choice would be made to use this name when using a null reference.

If anyone can point me to an authoritative explanation, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Entertainingly, you commented last year on the question in Jsight's link. =)

Comment: @Riggy: Ugh, my bad. I did the wrong search (java NullPointerException) instead of (java NullReferenException). I'm deleting the question to relinquish any ill-gotten rep.

Answer (score 5):

The statement that Java "officially has no pointers" is simply false. Just because you can't do arithmetic on it doesn't mean it's not a pointer. C is not the final authority for programming terminology.

The only people who get hung up over it are either C/C++ fans who want to disparage Java for its lack of power over the bare metal, or (unlikely, nowadays) marketing people who want to sell Java as a simpler, safer alternative to managers who've had bad experiences with C development.

From the [Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3.1):

> The reference values (often just
>   *references*) are *pointers* to these
>   objects, and a special null reference,
>   which refers to no object.

Comment: The disagreement on names of generally well-understood concepts is a fundamental problem across the entire computer science discipline. What's worse is a disagreement on names within a single language specification. What's the point of having two different words to refer to the same thing? Why do they need to tell us it's a pointer? To say that it's as efficient as a C/C++ pointer? In that case, they should've been aware of this naming discrepancy.