# Why java raises null pointer exception even if it doesn't support pointers?

Tags: java

I am been having a great curiosity.

I have written some java code & it is showing Null Pointer Exception. I am curious to know
Why java gives Null Pointer Exception even if it does not support pointers?

Comment: Admittedly, it could have been named: `NullReferenceException`...

Comment: @Aashish - legacy name may be as Java is written in C/C++?

Comment: and C doesn't have a NULL pointer exception. that's truly unfair :P

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436581/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pointer-and-a-reference-variable-in-java

Comment: @sylvainulg sure it does, it is just named "segmentation fault" or similarly.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648476/why-does-java-have-nullpointerexception-instead-of-nullreferenceexception 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101072/java-why-arent-nullpointerexceptions-called-nullreferenceexceptions

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: I wasn't expecting a reply on that one, but imvho, SEGFAULT is not part of C: it's something the OS stacks over the language. When programming your own OS or on a system that has no hardware memory protection (embedded systems), you "can" happily follow the NULL pointer, and observe the chaos of multiple part of your code sharing the same buffer for different purposes >_<

Comment: @sylvainulg real men do not need hardware protection ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java *does* support pointers (which you use everytime you have a `.` or a `[`).

It doesn't support pointer *arithmetic* - i.e. the ability to manipulate a pointer into another pointer using math.

To point this out to converted C/C++ programmers, they did not carry the C name over, but named it something else.  At the JVM level everything is pointers, but as Java programmers only see this when using references, the exception is badly named.

Answer (score 5):

the fact that there's no pointer arithmetic doesn't mean there's no pointer used in the language. And when it comes to Java, there is a *lot* of pointers, you just follow references with `.` rather than with `->`.

Answer (score 1):

`Object references` are nothing but pointers but they are not complex as `Pointers`. Have a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer) for difference.

Answer (score 1):

Java does indeed have pointers. They can have two kinds of values: (a) *references* to objects, or (b) null. This is the language used in the Specification.

Java pointers are however much more akin to Pascal pointers than to C pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a carryover from java's "C" herritage. It's also the parlance of the trade.