# NullPointerException should be called NullReferenceException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

We don't talk about pointers in Java, so why do we use the term NullPointerException in Java? I think the exception name NullReferenceException makes more sense.

Comment: Except that each Object variable you define is actually a pointer.

Comment: There are no pointers in java. The things you can do i.e. in c++ with pointers cannot be compared to those you can do in java with references

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception) and [Java: Why aren't NullPointerExceptions called NullReferenceExceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101072/java-why-arent-nullpointerexceptions-called-nullreferenceexceptions)

Comment: @ghoshak The second of those duplicates is a perfect match, good spot. The first is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: @Duncan thanks for the correction. The first one is about Null Pointer exception concept. It could be useful for understanding the topic.

Answer (score 1):

We talk about null pointer exceptions because the exception is named `NullPointerException`.  Why?  We will never know for sure ... unless someone from the original design team explains the history<sup>1</sup>.

The fact that there is an inconsistency really doesn't matter.  We all know what is meant.  It is interesting to note the Javadoc for `NullPointerException` sidesteps the issue by just talking about `null` without using the words "pointer" *or* "reference".

And before you suggest that the Java team should change the name of the exception, consider the impact that this would have.

---

<sup>1 - My theory is that early on (in the pre-Java 1.0 days) pointer and reference were used somewhat interchangeably.  Then they decided use "Java has references not pointers" as a point of difference with C and C++ ... but were left with a core exception that had an anomalous name.</sup>

Comment: Yes, I think of the same thing :)