# NullPointerException and NullReferenceException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nullreferenceexception

What is the difference between NullPointerException and NullReferenceException?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Why aren't NullPointerExceptions called NullReferenceExceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101072/java-why-arent-nullpointerexceptions-called-nullreferenceexceptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NullPointerException - The Java exception thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.

NullReferenceException - The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to reference (or use) a null or uninitialized object.

There is no 'NullReferenceException' in Java. Java has an equivalent class 'NullPointerException'.

Answer (score 11):

There is no `NullReferenceException` in Java. It's a .NET class, which is the equivalent of Java's `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

Java using `NullPointerException` instead of `NullReferenceException`. So there is no `NullReferenceException` in Java.